# MS SQL: return HTML from SQL PIVOT RESULTS with dynamic name/number of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, html-table, dynamic-sql

I am using MS-SQL 2008 and have a dynamic SQL query in a Stored Proc. that generates results using PIVOT.  The last columns of the pivot table can change both in the number of columns and the names based on user provided parameters.

The user is able to select/provide the number of months prior to the current month that they want to see results for.

```
Example Results: (User selects 2 months)
Product  DataDescript          2015-06    2015-05
-------  --------------------  -------    -------
Apples   AVG_Days_To_Ripen      15          18
Peaches  AVG_Days_To_Shipping   03          08

Example Results: (User selects 3 months)
Product  DataDescript          2015-06    2015-05    2015-04
-------  --------------------  -------    -------    -------
Apples   AVG_Days_To_Ripen      15          18        20
Peaches  AVG_Days_To_Shipping   03          08        07
```

I know how to return HTML (XML) results from a static dataset, but I am having a hard time thinking through how I would do it with a data set that is dynamic like this.

**Typically When I'm doing An HTML table based off of a static set of columns 
I usually do something similar to the following:**

```
SET @vMyHTMLTABLE = (

    '< table>
        < TR>
        < TH> WIDTH ="10%">Column1_Header < /TH>                                                    
        < TH> WIDTH ="10%">Column2_Header < /TH>
        < TH> WIDTH ="10%">Column3_HEader < /TH>
        < /TR>' 
    +   CAST((SELECT
                CASE WHEN (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by emt.Email_RUID ASC ) %2) = 0 THEN 'evn' ELSE 'odd' END as [td/@class],'Col1ID' as [td/@id] ,(emt.Column1)  as 'td','',
                CASE WHEN (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by emt.Email_RUID ASC ) %2) = 0 THEN 'evn' ELSE 'odd' END as [td/@class],'Col2ID' as [td/@id] ,(emt.Column2) as 'td','',
                CASE WHEN (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by emt.Email_RUID ASC ) %2) = 0 THEN 'evn' ELSE 'odd' END as [td/@class],'Col3ID' as [td/@id] ,(emt.Column3) as 'td'
            FROM @t_MyEmailTable emt
            WHERE 
            ORDER BY emt.Email_RUID ASC
            FOR XML PATH('tr'), ELEMENTS ) AS nvarchar(max))
    + '< /table>'

)
```

**To Generate my Dynamic Pivot table I'm doing something like this:**

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName        NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get my list of dynamic pivot Columns 
    SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') + QUOTENAME(LEFT(CAST(MyMonths.[YoMo] AS DATE),7))
        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT fr.[YoMo] FROM MyDB.dbo.FinalResults fr) AS MyMonths


SET @DynamicPivotQuery = (
          N'SELECT 
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by DataAsOf ASC ) AS [RowNum]
                ,CASE 
                    WHEN (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by DataAsOf ASC ) %2) = 0 THEN ''evn'' 
                    ELSE ''odd'' 
                END                 AS [class]
                ,LEFT(DataPoint,3)  AS [Act]
                ,RIGHT(DataPoint,3) AS [Pct]
                , *     
                FROM (
                        select distinct          
                              fr.[Product]                    AS [Product]
                            , fr.[DataDescript]               AS [DataDescript] 
                            , LEFT(CAST(fr.[YoMo] AS DATE),7) AS [YoMo]     
                            , fr.[DataValue]                  AS [DataValue]    

                        FROM MyDB.dbo.FinalResults fr   
                        join MyDB.dbo.FinalGroups g
                        ON fr.GID = g.GID
                     ) AS D                                
                PIVOT(
                        MAX(D.DataValue) FOR  D.YoMo IN(' + @ColumnName + ')
                     ) AS P 

                order by Product, DataDescript
                ') -- END: SET @DynamicPivotQuery

        EXEC tempdb.dbo.sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery --TempDB because source DB is in SQL 2000 Compat mode.
```

Any thoughts or insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why does having dynamic columns make it different?   What method are you using to generate HTML when it's static?

Comment: Great question. I've now added a quick example back into the original post.  There may be betters ways, and I'm open to anything that could work. this is just how I've typically made a quick html table where I have alternating "class" of odd/evn so I can apply CSS  and alternate the row colors.

Comment: Try doing your dynamic pivot a bit differently and you should then be able to incorporate the html characters you need - see this article describing dynamic pivoting: https://thesqlserverdeveloper.blogspot.com/2018/02/performing-dynamic-pivot.html?view=magazine